# функция возвращает функцию, typedef

Tags: c, typedef

```
typedef double (*d3vptr)[3];
typedef d3vptr (*search_for_vec_fptr)(d3vptr, int, double);
search_for_vec_fptr set_sr_func(int num, search_for_vec_fptr func);
```

Есть задание описать функцию set_sr_func без typedef.

Первый typedef я понял - это указатель на массив указателей массивов типа double по 3 элемента

Второй - это описание функции которая возвращает указатель на массив из указателей на массивы типа double и все эти массивы из double по 3 элемента, которая так же еще и принимает параметром такую же структуру.

Я не могу понять что возвращает set_sr_func и что конкретно она принимает вторым параметром.

```
double (*asd(double (*dp)[3], int i, double d))[3];
double (*(*asd_ptr)(double (*dp)[3], int i, double d))[3];
double (*(*asd_ptr)(double (*)[3], int, double))[3]; (ну или так можно)
```

Вот описал функцию search_for_vec_fptr без typedef и так же указатель для неё сделал. Дальше не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать (

Предполагаю что set_sr_func возвращает указатель на функцию которая возвращает структуру. Но что же все таки в параметре имеется ввиду.

Comment: _"это указатель на массив указателей массивов типа double по 3 элемента"_ - вроде бы это указатель на массив из 3 элементов double.

Comment: @Qwertiy, *d3vptr[3] - так да, как ptr[3], это будет указатель на массив из 3 элементов типа double, но (*d3vptr)[3] - это уже ptr[n][3], это уже указатель на матрицу в 3 столбца и n строк. Есть матрица matrix[10][10], *d3vptr[3] не сможешь matrix присвоить, а double (*d3vptr)[3] = matrix сделать сможешь, если без typedef делать. либо d3vptr new_ptr = matrix, если d3vptr в typedef объявлен.

Comment: Неправда. `int *x[3]` - массив из 3 указателей на int. `int (*x)[3]` - один указатель на массив из 3 int'ов.

Comment: Доказательство ([tio.run](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmktBAcStULBVMLeGcrQKgDwDay4oNzHaOBYoUK1QoQNGCrVwhUkwqQIdMEJIaWgla0Ik1RLBJhWllpQW5YGMrf3/HwA)): `int main()
{
  int x = 7;
  int *p = 0;

  int a[3] = { x, x, x };
  int *b[3] = { p, p, p };
  int (*c)[3] = &a;

  return 0;
}`

Comment: @Qwertiy, прошу прощения, да, int *x[3] - массив из 3 указателей на int.

Comment: Не понял, что ты про matrix дополнил. Покажи на tio.run. У меня ощущение, что оба не скомпилируются.

Comment: @Qwertiy, все верно, вы берете адрес массива a (&a). Если будет a[3][3], то адрес уже брать не нужно, в a и так будет лежать адрес первого массива (a[0][3])

Comment: У `int a[1000][3]` тоже адрес брать не надо. Потому что указатель на одномерный массив из 3 элементов. А у `int a[3][4]` что бери адрес, что нет - всё равно не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну да. Если a[3][4], то и указатель нужно обявъявлять как (*ptr)[4]

Comment: @Qwertiy, #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a[3][3] = {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}};
 int (*ptr)[3] = a;
 printf("%d\n", (*(ptr + 1))[0]);
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто механическая работа, поменял даже не разбираясь, что задано. Сначала переписал `typedef` на `#define`, потом вывел, во что же разворачивается последний, и скопипастил в код: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##hZFRS8MwFIXf8ysuDCQZE8b6tk5B5oZPKt3cy5BLTVMtbGlJk1ERf3tNstLWUfGtnPPl3HNveVFcv3Ne1/qzEIlIIcnN20EAHSfBqdCK7YPXkLSm16xZiljxD0xzhSfBMXUkPbsTyKSeNDksJAMolEJjqTA1klNLgzTHCQyBjrAZZGSnZ1LAfbB73ka0Yl3PylVsgc3qLlo@4Popwt1qieuGbt45mjbf7HdR1ovY4ibC9cvj0j0dTOxaD9m@tU3sJ/VWxplfKZP8YBIBiywvtRLx8barsI2mbvao6ku@zdkhsdE5XCHcQKmT@ZznRsNi4am/pgbMjW3v5n5iz@w26hF@EdoK7tIXV7MK@5ewY136Mc4kZeSLAPj648rV70qE1riQcDYkBla0shLaKAnTkHzX9Q8)

```
typedef double (*d3vptr)[3];
typedef d3vptr (*search_for_vec_fptr)(d3vptr, int, double);
search_for_vec_fptr set_sr_func(int num, search_for_vec_fptr func);

#define D3VPTR(x) double (*x)[3]
#define SEARCH_FOR_VEC_FPTR(x) D3VPTR((*x)(D3VPTR(), int, double))
#define SET_SR_FUNC(x) SEARCH_FOR_VEC_FPTR(x(int num, SEARCH_FOR_VEC_FPTR(func)))
SET_SR_FUNC(set_sr_func_2);

#include <iostream>
#define STR0(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR0(x)
auto &_ = std::cout << STR(SET_SR_FUNC(set_sr_func_3));

double (*(*set_sr_func_3(int num, double (*(*func)(double (*)[3], int, double))[3]))(double (*)[3], int, double))[3];

int main()
{
  auto *x = set_sr_func;
  x = set_sr_func_2;
  x = set_sr_func_3;
 
  return 0;
}
```

В результате тип приводится, значит он одинаковый, а не компилируется только из-за отсутствия функций:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9PBmw1.o: in function `main':
.code.tio.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `set_sr_func(int, double (*(*)(double (*) [3], int, double)) [3])'
/usr/bin/ld: .code.tio.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `set_sr_func_2(int, double (*(*)(double (*) [3], int, double)) [3])'
/usr/bin/ld: .code.tio.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `set_sr_func_3(int, double (*(*)(double (*) [3], int, double)) [3])'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/srv/wrappers/cpp-gcc: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

PS: Чую, можно было заставить компилятор как-то тип написать...

Comment: Про define даже как-то не думал) Но спасибо за готовую реализацию функции, я понял что нужно было ей в параметр - просто адрес функции которая описана как search_for_vec_fptr без параметров. Функция asd описана как search_for_vec_fptr, её и было достаточно передать параметром как &asd(или просто asd)